# Popover not including all information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have implement popovers in my rails app by putting the following in my application.js file

```
jQuery ->
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

In my view I have:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" title="More Information" data-content=<%= subtask.description %>>Show More Details </button>
```

This line is in an each loop that iterates through each subtask and prints them in a collapsible list. Everything works fine, except for the data-content isn't showing all the information. For example, the subtask description might be "Deliver to customer in x amount of time." However, the popover only shows "Deliver". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data-content="<%= subtask.description %>"
```

Comment: Wow! Don't I feel foolish! I've been trying to figure this out for days! Thanks!

Comment: I've been there! Good lucky! :)